# Lemma in Proof of Area Theorem for Conformal Mappings

Tags: complex-analysis

There is a theorem called the area theorem for conformal mappings, q.v. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_theorem_(conformal_mapping)

Setup:
Let $g(z) = z + b_0 + b_1 z^{-1} +b_2 z^{-2} + ...$ be holomorphic and injective on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \bar{\mathbb{D}},$ where $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ is the closed unit disk in $\mathbb{C}.$ Define $$E = \mathbb{C} \setminus g(\mathbb{C} \setminus \bar{\mathbb{D}})$$ to be the omitted set of $g.$ Let $C_r = g(\{z : |z|=r\}),$ for $r>1.$  By the Jordan curve theorem, $\mathbb{C} \setminus C_r$ consists of two connected components, one bounded and the other unbounded. Let $E_r$ be the bounded of these two regions.

Question: why do we have $E \subset E_r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g$ fixes $\infty$, $g$ obviously sends the exterior of the $r$-disc into the complement of $E_r$, so in particular all the values not taken by $g$ must be inside $E_r$ and since $r>1$ they cannot be on the boundary since that is also taken by $g$ by its definition

Comment: I agree $g(\{z : |z|>r\}) \subset E_r^c,$ but why is everything in $E_r^c$ hit by $g$?

Comment: By definition since $C_r = g(\{z : |z|=r\})$ and g is a conformal hence open mapping it means that it sends ${z : |z|>r}$ into a component of $\mathbb{C} \setminus C_r$ (the sets of points in a component of $\mathbb{C} \setminus C_r$ taken or missed by $g(\{z : |z|>r\})$ are both open, hence one is empty, the other the full component - if $g(z_n)$ converges to $w$ inside the component, $z_n$ cannot converge at the boundary since $g$ is continuos 1-1 on the full disc exterior due to $r>1$, so $z_n$ has a convergent subsequence - could be at infinity of course -, so $w$ is in the image of $g$

Comment: (cont from above to make it clearer) $z_n$ has a convergent subsequence - meaning inside ${z : |z|>r}$ strictly not at the boundary, though it can converge to infinity of course if $w = \infty$ in the component of $\mathbb{C} \setminus C_r$; this shows that the points not taken by $g$ in a component of $\mathbb{C} \setminus C_r$ form an open set, while $g$ being open implies that the points taken by $g$ form an open set

Comment: Why can't the $z_n$ converge to $\{z: |z|=r\}$?

Comment: Let $z_n$ or a subsequence converges to $z, |z| = r$; since $ r > 1$, $g(z_n)$ converges to $g(z)$, so $w = g(z)$ belongs to $C_r$ by definition, contradiction